# Listing all members group in a organizational unit

Tags: powershell, active-directory, ldap

I have the 2008 AD admin center with powershell. I am trying to get a list of all users of a OU that contains groups that change daily.

so for example the OU Temp has two groups ABC and DEF but tomorrow will have GHI and JFK. In AD I have found this ldap search works for one group at a time:

```
(&(objectClass=user)(memberof=CN=ABC,OU=Temp,DC=xxx,DC=yyy,DC=zzz))
```

But is there a way to find all members of all groups ABC,DEF,GHI,or JFK at the same time?

Answer (score 0):

Construct a search request using the following parameters:

- base object: `OU=Temp,DC=xxx,DC=yyy,DC=zzz`
- scope: `one` (if all groups are one level subordinate to `ou=temp`, `sub` otherwise)
- filter: `(&)` (some broken servers and APIs do not support this legal filter, if so, use `(objectClass=*)` instead)
- requested attributes: `member`

If access controls permit for the authorization state of the connection, the server will return a list of groups, and the `member` attribute(s) for each of those groups, in this case, below `ou=temp`.

#### see also

- [LDAP: Mastering Search Filters](http://www.ldapguru.info/ldap/mastering-ldap-search-filters.html)
- [LDAP: Search best practices](http://www.ldapguru.info/ldap/ldap-search-best-practices.html)
- [LDAP: Programming practices](http://www.ldapguru.info/ldap/ldap-programming-practices.html)

Answer (score 0):

Does this work for you?

```
$Groups = 'ABC','DEF','GHI','JFK'

$group_query = 
 $(foreach ($group in $groups){
 "(memberof=CN=$Group,OU=Temp,DC=xxx,DC=yyy,DC=zzz)"
 }) -Join ''

$Query = "(&(objectClass=user)(|$Group_Query))"

$query

(&(objectClass=user)(|(memberof=CN=ABC,OU=Temp,DC=xxx,DC=yyy,DC=zzz)(memberof=CN=DEF,OU=Temp,DC=xxx,DC=yyy,DC=zzz)(memberof=CN=GHI,OU=Temp,DC=xxx,DC=yyy,DC=zzz)(memberof=CN=JFK,OU=Temp,DC=xxx,DC=yyy,DC=zzz)))
```